# The user gets rewards after reaching the time interval ,its happened one time only, it have to continues until the user withdraw his funds,how to fix

Tags: solidity, remix

```
function mintreward(uint256 tokenId,string memory link) public  {
        require(block.timestamp>=rewardInterval ,"Tokens are only available after correct time period has elapsed");
        MyNFT obj = MyNFT(_MyNFTContractAddress);
        require(stakes[msg.sender] >= minimumStakes, "You Dont have enough balances");
        require(!isMinted[msg.sender], "You claimed your NFT already");
        isMinted[msg.sender] = true;
        obj.safeMint(msg.sender,tokenId,link);   
        
    }
```

Comment: Setting `isMinted[msg.sender] = true` will cause a revert the next time the function is called because the `require(!isMinted[msg.sender],..)` statement.

Comment: @Ismael I want to give the reward after reaching the time interval, after claiming the reward the user's time interval has to be reset so that the user can claim their reward continuously until they withdraw their funds, but I don't get ideas regarding this

Comment: Something like that is doable. It could keep track how many tokens it has minted and how many remains to be minted, and allow minting while remaining is greater than zero. For the intervals you could keep track of the last time minted and increment allowance for new intervals.